# Issue with new design: Suggested edit review page is clipped on the right side

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Saw an edit request.

[image]

Right side clipped in both Chrome and FoxFire

Comment: Happening on my machine to.

Comment: Was just taking the screen shot of this one too

Comment: I needed to step away, wondering if other browsers worked or all showed bug?

Answer (score 3):

I have pushed a fix for this to our dev server. The change will go out after our next production build.

Comment: Hi Jin. How frequent are the builds? Not going to watch the clock, just curious, hours, days, weeks?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer we do production builds nightly during the week days. Not sure if there will be another prod build tonight since it's the weekend. But definitely by next Monday.